# How to improve the send/receive speed of this Python socket?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking, ipc

The module [`multiprocessing.connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-listeners-clients) provides a nice wrapper around `socket` to send/receive messages without having to manually deal about message lengths etc.:

> Usually message passing between processes is done using queues or [...]
> However, the **multiprocessing.connection** module allows some extra flexibility. It basically gives a high level message oriented API for dealing with sockets or Windows named pipes. It also has support for digest authentication [...]

If you run these 2 codes on Windows:

```
# SERVER
import multiprocessing.connection, time
listener = multiprocessing.connection.Listener(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
conn = listener.accept()
t0 = time.time()
msg = conn.recv_bytes()
print(time.time()-t0)  # 0.305 !
```

```
# CLIENT
import multiprocessing.connection, time
conn = multiprocessing.connection.Client(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
s = b'a' * 32_000_000
t0 = time.time()
conn.send_bytes(s)
print(time.time()-t0)  # 0.005
```

On average I get ~300 milliseconds to receive the byes, which is a lot for only 32 MB of data (i5 computer).

I did other tests with 100MB and it's worse: 1.84 seconds!

**How to improve the speed of a `multiprocessing.connection` bytes reception?**

---

Edit (server: 1.84 seconds for 100MB data transferred on Windows; note that I have only 0.17 s on a Linux VPS):

```
# SERVER
import multiprocessing.connection, time
listener = multiprocessing.connection.Listener(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
conn = listener.accept()
print(conn.recv_bytes())   # hello
print(conn.recv_bytes())   # hello
t0 = time.time()
msg = conn.recv_bytes()
print(time.time()-t0)  # 1.843 seconds!

# CLIENT
import multiprocessing.connection, time
conn = multiprocessing.connection.Client(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
s = b'a' * 100_000_000
conn.send_bytes(b'hello')
time.sleep(1)               # hello and time.sleep to avoid counting the initial connection time in the measurement
conn.send_bytes(b'hello')   
t0 = time.time()
conn.send_bytes(s)
print(time.time()-t0)
```

Comment: See my "edited" edit with 100MB, here it's 1.84 seconds, and it's not due to the initial connection time, do you have the same with my "edit" code?

Comment: Note that the edited code still has a similar problem: Constructing the ``msg`` takes a bit, and is on the same timescale than the delay between the two processes. Still, *every* timings on my system is far away from 1.84 *s* – but I'm running MacOS, not Windows. Mind, the only Mac/Win difference I know for this kind of task is for unix sockets, which should not be relevant when connecting via IPv4 (even if it's the loopback device). If you want to tweak the test, it might be better to test the *roundtrip* by send from the client, recv and send from the listener, and recv in the client again.

Comment: For me the client reports 0.05 s, and the server 0.14s on a Windows machine, not sure if that's in the same ballpark as MisterMiyagi's timing.

Comment: @hugovdberg Thanks for having tested (did you test with 100 MB or 32 MB?). 0.14s is still a lot for less than 32MB.

Comment: I tested the 100MB variant

Comment: @hugovdberg I have client 0.09 s / server 0.17 s on a Linux VPS. This is a big difference with Windows 1.84 s! So my problem may be linked to my local Windows networking settings (?).