# Speed of socket send/recv on Windows

Tags: python, windows, performance, sockets, networking

On Windows + Python 3.7 + i5 laptop, it takes 200ms to receive 100MB of data via a `socket`, that's obviously very low compared to the RAM speed.

**How to improve this socket speed on Windows?**

```
# SERVER
import socket, time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
t0 = time.time()
while True:
    data = conn.recv(8192)  # 8192 instead of 1024 improves from 0.5s to 0.2s
    if data == b'':
        break
print(time.time() - t0)  # ~ 0.200s

# CLIENT
import socket, time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
a = b"a" * 100_000_000  # 100 MB of data
t0 = time.time()
s.send(a)
print(time.time() - t0)  # ~ 0.020s
```

Note: The question [How to improve the send/receive speed of this Python socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71410848/how-to-improve-the-send-receive-speed-of-this-python-socket) is about a *wrapper* around `socket`, so I wanted to test directly with a pure `socket`, and no wrapper.

Comment: I tried to check the performance with much bigger data (several GiB). First, I discovered a silent bug due to an integer overflow limiting sent data to 2 billions bytes. Then, I was able to reproduce this issue. Most of the time is surprisingly spend in the kernel and ws2_32.dll... I confirm this is is awfully slow. I can barely receive data at 1 GiB/s on a machine Xeon with a RAM capable of reaching 14 GiB/s in sequential and 39 GiB/s in parallel. The CPU is relatively saturated during this process. This is a shame.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment @JérômeRichard, can you post your observations as an answer, with more details (which Win version, etc.)? It will help to isolate the problem.

Comment: Increase the size of the socket receive buffer drastically, to a megabyte or more. This will allow the sender to send faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** based on the fact gathered mainly on my machine (and confirmed on another machine) on which I can reproduce a similar behaviour, the issue appear to mainly come from an **inefficient implementation of the Windows networking TCP stack**. More specifically, Windows performs a lot of **temporary-buffer copies** that cause the RAM to be intensively used. Furthermore, the overall resources are not efficiently used. That being said, the *benchmark can be also improved*.

---

### Setup

The main target platform used in to perform the benchmark have the following attributes:

- OS: Windows 10 Famille N (version 21H1)
- Processor: [i5-9600KF](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/190884/intel-core-i59600kf-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz/specifications.html)
- RAM: 2 x 8GiB DDR4 channels @ 3200GHz capable of reaching up to 40 GiB/s in practice.
- CPython 3.8.1

Please keep in mind that results can differ from one platform to another.

---

### Improving the code/benchmark

First of all, the line `a = b"a" * 100_000_000` take a bit of time which is included in the timing of the server since the client is connected before executing it and the server should accept the client during this time. It is better to *move this line before* the `s.connect` call.

Additionally, a buffer of 8192 is very small. Reading 100 MB by chunks of 8 KiB means that 12208 C calls must be performed and probably a similar number of system calls. Since **system calls are pretty expensive** as they tend to take at least few millisecond on most platform, it is better to **increase the buffer size** to at least 32 KiB on mainstream processors. The buffer should be small enough to fit in fast CPU cache but also big enough to reduce the amount of system calls. On my machine, using a 256 KiB buffer results in a 70% speed up.

Moreover, you need to **close the socket** in the client code for the server code not to hang on. Indeed, otherwise `conn.recv` should wait for incoming data. In fact, checking if `data == b''` is not a good idea as this is not a safe way to check if the stream is over. You need to send the size of the buffer sent or wait for a given predefined size. For example, the stream can be interrupted prematurely. Alternatively, the client can close the connection and the server will not always be directly notified (it can sometime take a very long time although it is fast on the loopback).

Here is the modified/improved benchmark:

```py
# CLIENT
import socket, time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
a = b"a" * 100_000_000  # 100 MB of data
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
t0 = time.time()
s.send(a)
s.close()
print(time.time() - t0)

# SERVER
import socket, time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
s = 0
t0 = time.time()
while True:
    data = conn.recv(256*1024)
    s += len(data)
    if s == 100_000_000:
        break
print(time.time() - t0)
```

I repeated the `s.send` call and the `recv`-based loop 100 times so to get stable results. With that I can reach 2.2 GiB/s. TCP sockets tends to be pretty slow on most platforms, but this result is clearly not great (Linux succeed to achieve a substantially better throughput).

On a different machine with Windows 10 Professional, a Skylake Xeon processor and a RAM reaching 40 GiB/s, I achieved 0.8~1.0 GiB/s which is very bad.

---

### Analysis

A profiling analysis show that the client process often saturate the TCP buffer and sleep for a short time (20~40 ms) waiting for the server to receive data. Here is an example of scheduling of the two processes (the top one is the server, the middle one is the client, the bottom one is a kernel thread and the light-green parts are idle time):

[image: process scheduling]

One can see that the server is not immediately awaken when the client fill the TCP buffer which is a missed-optimization of the Windows scheduler. In fact, the scheduler could wake up the client before the server starvation so to reduce latency issues. Note that a non-negligible part of the time is spent in a kernel process and the time slice are matching with the client activity.

Overall, 55% of the time is spend in the `recv` function of ws2_32.dll, 10% in the `send` function of the same DLL, 25% in synchronization functions, and 10% in other functions including ones of the CPython interpreter. Thus, the modified benchmark is **not slowed down by CPython**. Additionally, **synchronizations are not the main source of slowdown**.

When processes are scheduled, the memory throughput goes from 16 GiB/s up to 34 GiB/s with an average of ~20 GiB/s which is pretty big (especially considering the time taken by synchronizations). This means **Windows performs a lot of big temporary buffer copies**, especially during the `recv` calls.

Note that the reason why the Xeon-based platform is slower is certainly because the processor only succeed to reach 14 GiB/s in sequential while the i5-9600KF processor reach 24 GiB/s in sequential. The Xeon processor also operate at a lower frequency. Such things are common for server-based processors that mainly focus on *scalability*.

A deeper analysis of ws2_32.dll show that nearly all the time of `recv` is spent in the obscure instruction `call qword ptr [rip+0x3440f]` which I guess is a kernel call to copy data from a kernel buffer to the user one. The same thing applies for `send`. This means that the **copies are not done in user-land but in the Windows kernel itself**...

If you want to share data between two processes on Windows, I strongly advise you to use **shared memory** instead of sockets. Some message passing libraries provide an abstraction on top of this (like ZeroMQ for example).

---

### Notes

Here is some notes as pointed out in the comments:

If increasing the buffer size does not impact significantly the performance, then it certainly means that the code is already memory bound on the target machine. For example, with a 1 DDR4 memory channel @ 2400 GHz common on 3-year old PC, then the maximum practical throughput will be about 14 GiB/s and I expect the sockets throughput to be clearly less than 1 GiB/s. On much older PC with a basic 1 channel DDR3, the throughput should even be close to 500 MiB/s. The speed should be bounded by something like `maxMemThroughput / K` where `K = (N+1) * P` and where:

- `N` is the number of copy the operating system perform;
- `P` is equal to 2 on processor with a write-through cache policy or operating system using non-temporal SIMD instructions, and 3 otherwise.

Low-level profilers show that `K ~= 8` on Windows. They also show that `send` performs an efficient copy that benefit from non-temporal stores and quite saturate the RAM throughput, while `recv` seems not to use non-temporal stores, clearly does not saturate the RAM throughput and performs a lot more reads than writes (for some unknown reason).

On NUMA system like recent AMD processors (Zen) or multi-socket systems, this should be even be worse since the interconnect and the saturation of NUMA nodes can slow down transfers. Windows is known to behave badly in this case.

AFAIK, ZeroMQ has multiple backends (aka. "Multi-Transport") and one of them operate with TCP (default) while another operate with shared memory.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer and these benchmarks!

Comment: Note: For me, increasing the buffer from 8KB to 256KB and other benchmark modifications didn't change much: I still have ~200ms for 100MB, i.e. a very poor 500MB/s.

Comment: 3/n As a conclusion, do you think `socket` is probably limited at the order of magnitude of ~ 2 GB/s on Windows? Does this mean Redis (which uses networking, so, sockets probably?) is also limited at 2 GB/s on Windows? Same for ZeroMQ (which also uses sockets, is that right? https://zeromq.org/languages/python/): does it suffer from the same limitation on Windows?

Comment: 4/n Last comment ;) About your last paragraph, you speak about ZeroMQ: does it really use shared memory? Or rather sockets as well? [Here](https://zeromq.org/languages/python/) it seems to uses TCP socket.

Comment: This certainly means that the code is already memory bound on your machine. My machine has been designed to have a high throughput and most machine have a much lower throughput. For example, if you have a common 1 DDR4 memory channel @ 2400 GHz common on 3-year old PC, then the maximum practical throughput will be about 14 GiB/s and I expect the sockets throughput to be clearly less than 1 GiB/s. On much older PC with a basic 1 channel DDR3, the throughput should even be close to 500 MiB/s. I do expect the speed to be bounded by something like `maxMemThroughput/10` and even `/15` on x86-64.

Comment: If you use a NUMA system like recent AMD processors (Zen) or multi-socket systems, then this should be even be worse since the interconnect and the saturation of NUMA nodes can slow down transfers. Windows is known to behave badly in this case. There has been update to optimize this case a bit but this is still a mess. Note that, with shared memory, AFAIK you should be able to reach something close to the maximum throughput (ie. >10x higher performance). Note that you should still possibly care a bit about NUMA even with that.

Comment: I do not use ZeroMQ much but AFAIK they provide several *different backend* and one of them operate with TCP while another operate with shared memory. The default one may be TCP. Their [website](https://zeromq.org/) explicitly mention IPC (inter-process communication that usually means shared-memory) in the "Multi-Transport" section.

Comment: Thanks again! For future reference / future readers, it would be great to include these comments in the question.

Answer (score -3):

Don't make two calls to `send` if you have a bunch of data you want to send at the same time. When the implementation sees the first `send`, it has no reason to think there is going to be a second one, so sends the data immediately. But when it sees the second `send`, it has no reason to think there won't be a third one, and so delays sending the data to try to aggregate a full packet of data.

This would actually be fine if they were two distinct application-level messages and the party on the other side acknowledged the first message. But that's not the case here.

If you are designing an application-level protocol to work with TCP, you have to work with TCP if you care about performance.

If you don't have application-level messages, ensure you aggregate as much data as possible in each `send` call -- at least 4KB.

If you do have application-level messages that are acknowledged by the other side, try to include a full message in each `send` call.

But what you do in your code violates all these principles and gives the implementation no way to perform well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Note that the problem is exactly the same when there is a single `s.send()` (I only added a first send of "hello" just to print everything is ok on other side, but we can remove it, this was not the core of the question). I edited the question to remove this first send, the timing is exactly the same.

Comment: "*When the implementation sees the first `send`, it has no reason to think there is going to be a second one, so sends the data immediately*" - incorrect.  By default, TCP sockets have send coalescing (ie, the "Nagle algorithm") enabled, so that sends are buffered internally to produce more efficient network packets. You have to explicitly turn that off via the `SO_NODELAY` socket option to make sends "send immediately".

Comment: @RemyLebeau There's no coalescing on the first send for precisely the reason that I explained. There is on the second, again for precisely the reason that I explained.